# How can I produce TypeInformation from generic type in scala

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to extend `DeserializationSchema` for class with generic type

```
class Foo[T] extends DeserializationSchema[T] {
...
  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[T] = TypeInformation.of(classOf[T])
}
```

but I'm getting

> class type required but T found   override def getProducedType:
>   TypeInformation[T] = TypeInformation.of(classOf[T])

any idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of : class type required but T found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567370/how-to-get-rid-of-class-type-required-but-t-found)

Comment: [Class type required but T found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591957/class-type-required-but-t-found/20604596)

Comment: [Scala: class type required but T found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172958/scala-class-type-required-but-t-found)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/types_serialization.html)

> For generic types, you need to “capture” the generic type information
>   via the TypeHint:

So you can make it compile like this

```
class Foo[T] extends DeserializationSchema[T] {
...
  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[T] = TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint[T]{})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deriving `classOf` from `T`, you can require an implicit `TypeInformation[T]` as part of `Foo`'s declaration:

```
class Foo[T](implicit typeInformation: TypeInformation[T]) extends DeserializationSchema[T] {
  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[T] = typeInformation

  override def deserialize(message: Array[Byte]): T = ???

  override def isEndOfStream(nextElement: T): Boolean = ???
}
```